# Azure App Service Deploy error: "msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server-2019

I am using Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1 version.
I'm trying to deploy a .Net Core Web API from a built *.zip file and I am getting a weird error when trying to connect to the app for deployment(Task: Azure App Service Deploy(3.*)).

Here is a sample of the error message:

2019-07-22T19:09:17.7807521Z Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7807958Z     at ChildProcess. (C:\agent_work_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.4.16\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:568:30)
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7808050Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7808194Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7809218Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7810272Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
2019-07-22T19:09:17.7810699Z    Retrying to deploy the package.

2019-07-22T19:09:18.0954502Z Info: Using ID 'e91f0d00-f62e-4918-8242-3215abeb8ecb' for connections to the remote server.
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2740289Z Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2740487Z     at ChildProcess. (C:\agent_work_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.4.16\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:568:30)
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2740965Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2741020Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2741074Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2741146Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
2019-07-22T19:09:39.2741211Z    Retrying to deploy the package.

2019-07-22T19:09:39.5880914Z Info: Using ID 'd5158a2c-8fbe-4b69-83db-abc89116e8fa' for connections to the remote server.
2019-07-22T19:10:00.7577558Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2019-07-22T19:10:00.7583992Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let us know if this issue is intermittent or reproduces consistently? If the issue happens intermittently, please try to add `-retryInterval:6000 -retryAttempts:10` in Additional arguments under Publish Using web deploy option and re-queue the release.

In addition, For error **ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE** usually indicates Web Management Service or Remote Agent is not installed or unreachable on the remote computer. Could you please check the WMS is installed and running.

Comment: Thanks @LU Mike. I have added the -retryInterval:6000 -retryAttempts:10, but no luck. 
Then I change the build agent login type from Network Service Account to Local Account. Then its working as expected.